# iOS 11 causes several views to render with an offset?

Tags: ios

After updating to the iOS 11 SDK, many of the views in an app I'm working on are rendering with incorrect positions. For example two views that normally cover the screen are centered left and up from the center. Another view that normally sits at the bottom of the screen is now below the bottom (offscreen). I've checked the frames of these views in

I can post code, but this is a large project, and the issues only appeared after the iOS 11 update. Apple's [api changes](https://developer.apple.com/api-changes/) page does not have a link for iOS 11, so I'm not even sure where to start troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Just wanting to understand the whole picture. Are you using auto layout? Does this happen in the simulator and on a device?

Comment: It happens in the simulator and on device. I don't think we're using auto layout for these views (the view's frames are set manually in Objective-C).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unsure what the root cause of this is or why it only started happening after the update to iOS 11, but this is my solution:

```
self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

This fixed the cases in our app where fullscreen overlay views were being rendered above and to the left of the screen.